# Can not get IMSI and IMEI with AT commands

Tags: serial-port, raspberry-pi, at-command, modem

I am using a raspberry pi to communicate with an SL8092 modem from Sierra. I am able to communicate with the device via the /dev/ttyUSB4 using minicom.

Sending AT commands returns the following answers:

```
> AT
< OK
> AT+CSQ
< +CSQ: 30,99
>AT+COPS
<+COPS: 2
```

But when sending AT+CIMI or AT+CGSN, I am expecting to get the IMSI and the IMEI. Unfortunately it's not the case - the only answer I get is just "OK".

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this document?

http://source.sierrawireless.com/resources/airprime/minicard/2130617_ac_ap_umts_supported_at_command_reference/

Free signup on sierrawireless if you don't have login.

From document:

!GRELIMEI

Return the modem’s production TAC (Type Allocation Code).

(TAC is first 8 characters,then padded with zeroes).

For example, if IMEI is 289258158732085, the TAC is 289258150000000.

Usage:

- Query: AT!GRELIMEI?
- Response: [TAC] OK
- Purpose: Return the [TAC] assigned to the modem.
- Parameters: [TAC] 15-character string. (TAC is the first 8 characters, and remainder of string is zeropadded.)

Example:
If the modem’s IMEI is 289258158732085, !GRELIMEI returns 289258150000000.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on android phone.
AT+GSN

Answer (score 0):

You can try using these AT commands and find out which are valid with your device. This is for the phone so I am not sure it works with your Pi.

- API
- AT+IMEINUM
- AT+DEVCONINFO
- AT%IMEI?

You can find out some useful AT commands here: https://atcommands.org/atdb/